# Jest - I have a nested error when more than one file

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have two test files, when I rename and comment one of them, the test will pass successfuly, otherwise will always throw this error:

```
 FAIL  src/features/user/auth/register.resolver.test.ts (10.045 s)
  ● Register › a new user with a valid form › call register resolver and return the registered user

    Tests cannot be nested. Test "encountered a declaration exception" cannot run because it is nested within "call register resolver and return the registered user".

      28 | `
      29 |
    > 30 | describe('Login', () => {
         | ^
      31 |   let dbConnection: Connection;
      32 |   let userRepository: UserRepository;
      33 |

      at Env.it (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:566:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/user/auth/login.resolver.test.ts:30:1)

  ● Register › a new user with a valid form › the new user is persisted in database

    expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a non-null object

    Received has value: undefined

      81 |       });
      82 |
    > 83 |       expect(user).toMatchObject({
         |                    ^
      84 |         id: expect.any(String),
      85 |         username: registerInput.username,
      86 |         email: registerInput.email,

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/user/auth/register.resolver.test.ts:83:20)

  ● Register › a new user with an invalid form › returns the errors

    Tests cannot be nested. Test "encountered a declaration exception" cannot run because it is nested within "returns the errors".

      28 | `
      29 |
    > 30 | describe('Login', () => {
         | ^
      31 |   let dbConnection: Connection;
      32 |   let userRepository: UserRepository;
      33 |

      at Env.it (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:566:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/user/auth/login.resolver.test.ts:30:1)

 FAIL  src/features/user/auth/login.resolver.test.ts (10.298 s)
  ● Login › with a valid form › call login resolver and return the logged in user

    Tests cannot be nested. Test "encountered a declaration exception" cannot run because it is nested within "call login resolver and return the logged in user".

      27 | `
      28 |
    > 29 | describe("Register", () => {
         | ^
      30 |   let dbConnection: Connection;
      31 |   let userRepository: UserRepository;
      32 |

      at Env.it (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:566:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/user/auth/register.resolver.test.ts:29:1)

  ● Login › with an invalid form › returns an error [login]

    Tests cannot be nested. Test "encountered a declaration exception" cannot run because it is nested within "returns an error [login]".   

      27 | `
      28 |
    > 29 | describe("Register", () => {
         | ^
      30 |   let dbConnection: Connection;
      31 |   let userRepository: UserRepository;
      32 |

      at Env.it (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:566:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/features/user/auth/register.resolver.test.ts:29:1)

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       5 failed, 1 passed, 6 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.143 s
Ran all test suites.
```

And here the test files: https://gist.github.com/srgrcp/01fbbd4df391a90c25c8c60622bc2514

If I'm not wrong, the error says: "the  is nested within ", but these tests are in different files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.